# connecting to database

Tags: java, mysql, database, forms, button

can anyone help me how to connect my java forms to my mysql database?
i have this following codes but it didn't work...

```
private void saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    String value1 = textField1.getText();
    String value2 = textField2.getText();
    String value3 = textField3.getText();
    String value4 = textField4.getText();
    Connection con = null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Marketing";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String db = "Marketing";
    String user = "root";
    String pass = "";
    System.out.println(value1 + value2 + value3 + value4);
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, user, pass);
        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("insert into clients (idclients,    name, address, contact_person, contact_num) values(?,?,?,?,?)");
        st.setString(2, value2);
        st.setString(3, value3);
        st.setString(4, value4);
        st.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jPanel1, "Data is successfully inserted into database.");
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jPanel1, "Error in submitting data!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "not working" look like?  Help us help you - provide some worthwhile information.  And I'd recommend that you refactor that code to separate SQL from Swing.  As written, this code won't be very useful.

Comment: as a side comment ... opening a DB connection when handling an event is very BAD BAD BAD practice. Isolate that piece of code and reuse it ... look at the DAO pattern.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments and I'm sorry for giving little information about my problem. My error is that I can't save all the values to the database though I'm successfully connected. I get error in submitting data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem with  connection code :

```
url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Marketing
db  = Marketing

url + db = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MarketingMarketing
```

here you have to remove one extra marketing

Comment: yes I've noticed it now with all your suggestions that it's not right to code it that way so I changed it but I still can't submit the values I've inserted... it doesn't save to the database.

Answer (score 2):

One problem I can see straight away is that your PreparedStatement expects 5 parameters (1 - 5) yet you're only setting 3!
Secondly, I'm not sure why you use DriverManager.getConnection( url **+db** , ... ) when your database URL already contains a database name, so use just `DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass)`.
Having said that though, it would be good if you could clarify what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks, I did not notice the parameters. I already corrected it and  I changed the DriverManager codes with your suggestion but I still get the same error. My error is that I can't save all the values to the database though I'm successfully connected. I get error in submitting data.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this statement:

```
 con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, user, pass);
```

The getConnection method connect to database on url specified in 1st parameter. Here you combine 2 variables named `url` and `db` so your connection url will become: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MarketingMarketing` which may be not the thing you want. Use only `url` instead of `url + db`.

Comment: thanks.. I already change it but still i get the same error.. "cannot submit data". i can't submit the values I've inserted...